# Run iterative tests in XCTestCase on the same test

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I am attempting to run a UI Test in XCTestCase and when I am running it, I would like to run it multiple times with multiple different inputs.  Is there a straightforward way to run a test multiple times with different inputs?

I want to run a test with different inputs but only write the test once.  An example of this would be that I am trying to pass different user names in to verify behavior.

Comment: Some kind of loop would appear to be in order?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I know but I am not sure how to loop it in the test so the setup and tear down methods are called each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of sloppy because it executes `setUp()` once at the beginning unnecessarily but otherwise it gets the job done...

```
func testLoop() { 
    for parameter in myParameters {
       setUp()
       testToBeLooped(parameter: parameter)
       tearDown()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not worried about sloppy. I'll be testing this this weekend. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly running your assertions for each input in the same test I will advise to use [`XCTContext.runActivity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/activities_and_attachments/grouping_tests_into_substeps_with_activities) to specify activity name for each parameter input:

```swift
func testToBeLooped(parameter: Int) {
    print(parameter)
    XCTAssertEqual(0, parameter % 2)
}

func testLoop() {
    let myParameters = [1, 2, 3]
    for parameter in myParameters {
        XCTContext.runActivity(named: "Testing for parameter \(parameter)") { activity in
            setUp()
            testToBeLooped(parameter: parameter)
            tearDown()
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to visualize exactly which input parameters didn't pass assertions and which of the assertions failed for each in the test report:

[image: Testing assertion with activity]